# "Playing is fun." "To play is fun."

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

In my opinion identical in what they say. Is this correct or is there a subtle difference?Very rarely do I see the second form but it has to have the same meaning. What about "It is" constructions? "It is fun to play." can be said although with focus on the "it" but I am not sure if you can do this with gerunds, "It is fun playing." Id say no. But I think I heard something like "It was fun meeting you." Is there a stop in this "It was fun.Meeting you." When talking?

Comment: I think it all comes down to idiomatic usage. Playing in "playing  is fun"  can be a verb but also a noun and that probably makes the sentence more idiomatic than "to play is fun."

Comment: Difference between gerund and infinite.

Comment: No real difference in meaning. But note that it's not a gerund, it's a verb.

Comment: @BillJ: Professional session musician musically-inclined amateur: to *Your playing is fun, **my** playing is work*. That's a gerund, where the less idiomatic *verb* form would be ***You** playing is fun, **me** playing is work*. In OP's case it's ambiguous (though I can't really see that either interpretation would affect the semantics - it's essentially just a matter of syntax).

Comment: How can it be a verb? Explanation would be great only gerund makes sense to me.

Comment: Why do you think that "playing" in "It is fun playing" is a noun (gerund)?

Comment: I thought ing forms were either gerunds participles adjectives I also questioned the validity of that sentence but if its correct gerund would be the only one making sense to me. The verb form would be constructed with to in my opinion. I never knew they could be verbs so gerund was the most likely option for me.

Comment: "It is fun playing" and "It was fun meeting you" are a special kind of construction called "right dislocation" where the later element provides a referential interpretation/clarification of the pronoun "it". Note particularly the phonological "pause" between  the two elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no difference in meaning.

Both the gerund "playing" and the to-infinitive "to play" have been used as the subject of the sentence.  The usage of a gerund is more common than that of a to-infinitive at the start of a sentence, especially in informal English.

Answer (score 0):

"To play is fun" may be grammatically correct, but my native speaker ear doesn't detect it as so. I can't imagine another native speaker saying that. If I were to suspend my disbelief and accept that it is correct, then I'd say that the two sentences mean the same thing. It would be better to use "It is fun to play" though.